# How to fetch email from facebook SDK in unity?

Tags: json, facebook, email, unity-game-engine

I've already successfully got the full name of a user using json:

#region get facebook name
    //PUBLIC STATICS
    public static string fbname;
    private static string get_data;

```
public static string GetUserFBName()
{
    FB.API("me?fields=name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, UserCallBack);
    return fbname;
}

//USER CALLBACK
private static void UserCallBack(FBResult result)
{
    if (result.Error != null)
    {
        get_data = result.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        get_data = result.Text;
    }
    var dict = Json.Deserialize(get_data) as IDictionary;
    fbname = dict["name"].ToString();
}
#endregion
```

Now where do I begin with getting the email adress? I added the following to the permission:

```
    FB.Login("email", AuthCallBack);
```

Thanks!